# About the subject predicate object triplet in RDF

Tags: xml, rdf, n-triples

I have a question regaring writing triplets in RDF. According to the description http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#section-triples, it's been said that a predicate should be an URI.

But lets say if I want to write something like 
`<http://mydomain.com/#me>site-owner "http://mydomain.com"` then, how am I supposed to write a URI for site-owner. I am a bit confused. As give in this tutorial

http://videolectures.net/training06_sure_stsw/.
He has written rdf in xml as

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about=“#York”>
    <tel>6086592</tel>
</rdf:Description>
```

However, here the actual predicate tel is not in URI format. I am a bit confused. Even though one is using XML and the other is using NTriples, I think it should be same, isn't it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

tel in your example would expand to something like http://example.org/tel, it's using the default namespace for the document defined in the RDF element in the RDF/XML so it's still a URI.

Just coin a URI for site-owner and use that for defining that triple.  Better yet, try using standard vocabularies such as [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/) or [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/).

You may want to check out the [RDF primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/) if you have not already.  In fact, most of the resources on the w3c are quite good and you should start with those.